# Return multiple dates, if vald, in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using Excel 2013

I have 2 columns, `A` and `B` containing dates.

I wish to create a third column which should display, for every date in column `A`, at column `C` and same line, all dates from column `B` - if there are previous to the date appearing in column `A` and no further then 60 days. Dates are not sorted.

Went over lots of questions. Tried splicing all sorts. Index and lookup and aggregate. The desired result is something like:

`= if( 0=<(A1-B:B)<60, B:B, "")`

For every date in column `A`, it will show the valid dates from column `B`.

[Image that shows the breakdown of formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuU42.png)

In C2, for example, I'd like it to show the dates from B6 up to B1, since those are valid dates from B column in comparison with A2 (as well as for A3 thru A6 because that is the same date).

Answer (score 0):

I reached an answer:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B, SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$100<$A2)*($B$2:$B$100>$A2-60),
 ROW($B$2:$B$100)), COLUMNS($C$2:C$2))), "")
```

Thanks to dirdi, Akina & Rajesh for helping.